# Started netserver on remote machine, but netperf cannot make connection

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, azure, benchmarks

I'm using two azure machines to run a `TCP_STREAM` test from netperf between them.

The remote machine is called `mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west` and the local one is called `mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk`.

I follow these steps:

1. Start the `netserver` in the remote server at port `2333`:

```
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west-0001:~$ sudo netserver -p 2333
Starting netserver with host 'IN(6)ADDR_ANY' port '2333' and family AF_UNSPEC
```

make sure it is started:

```
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west-0001:~$ ps -ef | grep netserver
root        4139       1  0 16:16 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/netserver
root       26990       1  0 16:21 ?        00:00:00 netserver -p 2333
ubuntu     27011    1906  0 16:25 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto netserver

ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west-0001:~$sudo lsof -i tcp:2333
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
netserver 26990 root    3u  IPv6  66361      0t0  TCP *:2333 (LISTEN)
```

2. Get the IP address of the remote machine:

```
enP6064s1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      ether 00:0d:3a:f6:09:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
      RX packets 53433  bytes 76754512 (76.7 MB)
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
      TX packets 8200  bytes 1287344 (1.2 MB)
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
      inet 10.2.0.27  netmask 255.255.192.0  broadcast 10.2.63.255
      inet6 fe80::20d:3aff:fef6:999  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
      ether 00:0d:3a:f6:09:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
      RX packets 12508  bytes 80101094 (80.1 MB)
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
      TX packets 8136  bytes 1286894 (1.2 MB)
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
      inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
      inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
      loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
      RX packets 190  bytes 25942 (25.9 KB)
      RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
      TX packets 190  bytes 25942 (25.9 KB)
      TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Which shows the IP address for the west machine is 10.2.0.27!

3. Run netperf from the local machine

```
netperf -H 10.2.0.27 -p 2333 -D 0.5 -c -C -l 20 -t TCP_STREAM -P 0 -f g -- -b 2 -D -o throughput,throughput_units
```

and now it gives me:

```
establish control: are you sure there is a netserver listening on 10.2.0.27 at port 2333?
establish_control could not establish the control connection from 0.0.0.0 port 0 address family AF_UNSPEC to 10.2.0.27 port 2333 address family AF_INET
```

This is so confusing! Because I have verified that the netserver is listening on 10.2.0.27 at port 2333. Actually, the same procedure works fine on GCE's machines.

I wonder what may cause this and how to fix it.

Per comments from @waltinator, I looked at the `ip route`, `ufw status`, `sudo traceroute the-other-system` on both machine.

On the west machine:

```
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west-0001:~$ ip route
default via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.2.0.27 metric 100 
10.2.0.0/18 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.27 
168.63.129.16 via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.2.0.27 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.2.0.27 metric 100 
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west-0001:~$ ufw status
ERROR: You need to be root to run this script
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-west-0001:~$ sudo traceroute 10.1.0.62
traceroute to 10.1.0.62 (10.1.0.62), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
...
30  * * *
```

On the local machine:

```
ubuntu@jane-cr22-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-0001:~$ ip route
default via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.62 metric 100 
10.1.0.0/18 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.62 
168.63.129.16 via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.62 metric 100 
169.254.169.254 via 10.1.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.62 metric 100 
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-0001:~$ ufw status
ERROR: You need to be root to run this script
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-0001:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
ubuntu@mymachine-Standard-D8as-v4-premium-disk-0001:~$ sudo traceroute  10.2.0.27
traceroute to 10.2.0.27 (10.2.0.27), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
...
30  * * *
```

Besides, for the west machine, I've added an inbound port rule that has priority 100, allowing any source and destination, with port range 2333. But still, the local machine cannot connect with the remote one.

Comment: Look at `ip route`, `ufw status`, `sudo traceroute the-other-system` on BOTH.

Comment: @waltinator thanks for replying! Added the results of these 3 commands in the question.